# Vertical alignment of proof trees

Tags: bussproofs

Is it possible to vertically align two or more proof trees, typeset using bussproofs, so that the bottommost lines of the rules are at the same level? Consider for example the following:

```
\begin{center}
  \AxiomC{$(A_i)^{i \in 1..n}$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\vdash A$}
  \DisplayProof
  \qquad
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\vdash B$}
  \DisplayProof
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following produces what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\bottomAlignProof
  \AxiomC{$(A_i)^{i \in 1..n}$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\vdash A$}
  \DisplayProof
  \qquad
  \bottomAlignProof
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\vdash B$}
  \DisplayProof
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This almost does the trick, except that it aligns them at the bottom rather than at the line, so if the conclusion in each rule have different heights then it is still not completely aligned.

Comment: @ahovgaard: You are right. The above unfortunately only covers this case. If the text under the line has different heights, you could manually adjust the placement of one of the proofs by enclosing it in `  \raisebox{-6pt}{<proof>}`.  However, with this approach you have to manually adjust the distance that is needed to shift this proof to align with  the other proof.